# Multiple ssl certificates (multiple domains) to same spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application deployed to a virtual machine, with a valid ssl certificate enabled, everything works fine.

The thing is, I have a mydomain.com working (with ssl enabled), and now, I need to point mydomain.com.br to same application also with ssl enabled.

I did some research on google, about how to add more than one server.ssl.key-alias property, and did some tests but got no result.

From what I did so far, I think that I need to find a way to add another alias to my properties. Is this correct? If not, how can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you don't need to change your application. You only need to regenerate your certificate.

The certificate's "Subject Alternative Name" attribute contains other valid domain names for this certificate

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The problem is that I only have a single domain certificate :(
Now I know how to proceed, and what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Following your Subject, all that you need to do is to Purchase and Setup a wildcard Certificate as each Authority sign only a valid SSL for a single domain in case you bought a simple SSL, even you can buy EV ssl also.

But my answer for you is: Buy a wildcard SSL

Comment: Thanks!
As far as I understand, a wildcard certificate will work for *.mydomain.com, not for *.mydomain.com.*, but, I am not sure about this.

Comment: oh! if you are trying to use it into .com.* then try a look into this link https://www.gogetssl.com/multi-ssl/   I use always SSL from there

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks!
I got my ceriticate from there also, but, mine is single domain, I will need a new one.